# pinging dynamic IP server

Tags: ping, icmp

I invoked ping process on ubuntu, then while ping works the IP of server has been changed.

another ping process from the same machine showed me the correct IP, but the first process still printing old IP.

that can be variable in ping, initialized once when it start (I guess, anybody here can confirm it?).

however I wonder to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be an DNS Cache problem?
If you think yes, try that:
sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean start